# How to make contact form only send filled out parts of form?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, contacts

Basically, how can I make it so if a user fills out 3 / 4  fields that it just sends the 3 fields and ignores the fourth...so it looks like:

Field One: Filled out

Field Two: Filled Out

Field Four: filled out

Instead of:

Field One: Filled out

Field Two: Filled Out

Field Three:

Field Four: filled out

Thanks!!

Comment: It's up to you on your server-side code. You can check if there is a value; if not you do nothing related to this input.

Comment: Hello, you need to provide code (at least your contact form's) and what have you tried so far would also be nice.

Comment: If you using a HTML form and directing directly to PHP each field will be submitted regardless of wether it was empty or not, only disabled fields will not be sent along when the form is submitted. Using something like an AJAX request would allow you to check which fields were checked on the client side and only send those along but outside, but short of that the easiest way would be checking the input on the PHP side to check if the field was blank or not as tektiv mentioned. More information/code would be required for a more useful answer however.

Comment: Don't include the fourth value on your form at all. Or remove it prior to submission on the client side, then submit. Or create a custom form object inline. Or use a manual AJAX call, supplying only the fields you require. Or deal with it on the server side. Any number of solutions to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If first 3 are required, add `required` attribute in HTML input tag and in PHP you can simply check like this:

```
if ($_POST['field4th']) {
    // ... Do something here with 4 fields
} else {
    // ... Do something here with 3 fields
}
```